# Play Framework: parse "CompletionStage" (Java8) response

Tags: java, playframework, java-8

I am totally new to Java 1.8 and to Play Framework.
Just a simple question: from my application I have to call a REST web service thoroug Play framework and then parse the XML response in order to find some elements of interest.
My code, as I found on the guide, looks as follows:

```
WSRequest request = ws.url("http://example.com").setQueryParameter("paramKey", "paramValue");

CompletionStage<Document> documentPromise = request.get()
            .thenApply(WSResponse::asXml);
```

The question is: how do I parse the "documentPromise" result to find the elements inside the XML?

Thank you

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to, instead of use `WSResponse::asXml`, apply that method yourself and process it as needed. For example, if you just want to return the text of an element, given an id:

```
// (...)
.thenApply(res -> {
    Document doc = res.asXml();   
    Element e = doc.getElementById("someId");
    return ok(e.getTextContent());
});
```